# No permite introducir texto mediante teclado [C]

Tags: c, fgets, stdin

en el proyecto me pedian que midiese la longitud de una cadena que introduce el usuario y que en caso de tener solo el caracter de salto de linea que imprimiese un mensaje diciendo "longitud nula". Para esto pense en utilizar fgets pero como no lo habia usado antes no entiendo por que no me deja introducir texto mediante teclado. Cuando llamo a la funcion aparece en la consola el mensaje pero no me deja introducir una cadena y no se como solucionarlo.

```
void lee_cadena (char *mensaje, char *la_cadena)
{
  char cadena[500];
  int longitud;

  fprintf(stdout, "%s ", mensaje); //Este mensaje solicita que introduzca una cadena
  fgets(cadena, 500, stdin);
  sscanf(cadena, "%s", la_cadena);
  return;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema. A mi si me deja introducir texto por teclado y me lo imprime. Ahora, la pregunta del millón, ¿comprobaste si el búfer del teclado está sucio?, si lo llegara a estar, la función fgets no te pausará el programa porqué esta subrutina deja de leer caracteres hasta encontrar un salto de línea...

Comment: Creo que se guardaba un "\n" de la parte anterior del proyecto y por eso no me dejaba escribir, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Proba colocando la siguiente funcion antes de llamar a fgets

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Es para limpiar el buffer de entrada y asegurarnos que no contenga basura que puede alterar la lectura de fgets.

Espero tu comentario!

Saludos

Comment: Pues parece que ahora si funciona, debe ser por que guardaba el "\n" del intro. Muchas gracias!

Comment: La función `fflush` es para limpiar el búfer de salida. Por más que funcione en algunas ocasiones para borrar el búfer de entrada, no se lo debería de usar, por cuestión de portabilidad. Así que para no tener problemas, no se recomienda su uso (aquí está la documentación de dicha función: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/). En su reemplazo, se podría usar la siguiente instrucción para el limpiar el búfer de entrada: `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);`. De este modo, tu programa queda portable.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias